# lua oop starting out

Tags: oop, lua

I'm trying to get some code working from this video: [Lua Tutorial 9: OOP and Metatables](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22QTG81kJaQ) about 11 minutes into the video

I'm new to lua but i have programming experience so after going through the basics of the language i'd thought i'd learn some ways to do oop.
In my code i've replaced vector3 with Vector2 since i need to work in 2d for now.
Lua's powerful tables is something that is something i really need to understand to be more fluent in the language of coarse .

however i get an error:
**input:38: attempt to perform arithmetic on a table value (local 'v1')**

I have the same issue testing in: [the lua demo interpreter](https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo)
The code i'm trying out:

```
Vector2 = {x = 0, y = 0}
Vector2.prototype = {x = 0, y = 0}
Vector2.mt = {}
Vector2.new = function()
    local vec = {}
    setmetatable(vec, Vector2, mt)
    for k, v in pairs(Vector2) do
        vec[k] = v
    end
    return vec
end

Vector2.mt.__add = function(v1, v2)
    local vec = Vector2.new()
    vec.x = v1.x + v2.x
    vec.y = v1.y + v2.y
    return vec
end

function draw()
    local v1 = Vector2.new()
    local v2 = Vector2.new()
    v1.x = 10
    v1.y = 34
    v2.x = 20
    v2.y = 22
    v1 = v1 + v2
    print(v1.x)
end


draw()
```

Any thoughts.
Thanks.

Comment: this is not called OOP but prototype-based programming

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: A side note: do basic oop exercises to understand how meta tables work and used. you will learn syntax and spot such mistakes easily

Comment: you can use TypeScriptLUA which compiles typescript code into LUA bytecode. So you can use TypeScript  write yout classes with using OOP and then run it in LUA VM. Repository is on github https://github.com/ASDAlexander77/TypeScriptLUA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a typo when copied text from the video.

The line `setmetatable(vec, Vector2, mt)` should be `setmetatable(vec, Vector2.mt)`

Comment: I love you :)     I think I looked at the code like 50 times before posting here.  Thanks